# Expectation of Quadratic variation of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, expected-value, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

For $V_n$ = $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|W(t_{i+1})-W(t_i)|^2$ where $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion, I know the following:

$$
E[V_n] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} E[(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^2] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (t_{i+1} - t_i) = T
$$

Now, suppose I need to find the expectation of $Y_n$ which is defined as follows:
$$
Y_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^3|
$$

How can I solve this? I have done the following and would like to know if I am on the right track:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^3| = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}-W(t_i))(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^2| \\[2ex]
\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}-W(t_i))| |(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^2| \\[2ex]
\leq max_{i=0,1,...,n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}-W(t_i))| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^2|
$$

So:

$$
E[Y_n] = E\bigg[max_{i=0,1,...,n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}-W(t_i))| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^2|\bigg]
$$

Now, I am a bit confused because I do not know how I can take the expectation of the terms. Does the following make sense? (are the terms independent so I can do this):

$$
E[Y_n] = E\bigg[max_{i=0,1,...,n-1} |(W(t_{i+1}-W(t_i))|\bigg]  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} E[|(W(t_{i+1}) - W(t_i))^2|] \\[2ex]
E[Y_n] = 0 \times T 
$$

Comment: Your approach is only producing an inequality.  Do you just want that, or an actual equality for $E[Y_n]$?

Comment: I'm basically trying to show that $Y_n$ converges in probability to 0 and that requires that I show the expectation as n goes to infinity is equal to 0 first and that's what I am struggling with

Comment: Is there a direct reason as to why your last line converges to 0? And given the fact that you used the absolute third moment to solve this, does this follow in higher dimensions? Say if I needed to find the cubic variation or any p-th variation?

Comment: I added an answer (and deleted the comments which had some typos).

Comment: Thank you! I will try what you said out for a couple other p values so I understand it completely :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to bound the random variable $Y_n$ and then take the expectation of the bound.  It is easier to take the expectation first and then bound it.

We know that $W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i} \sim N(0, t_{i+1}-t_i)$.  Now one can see  by scaling that the absolute third moment of $N(0, \sigma^2)$ must be of the form $c \sigma^{3}$. (In fact $c = 2^{3/2}/\sqrt{\pi}$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)). So we have $E[|W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}|^3] = c (t_{i+1}-t_i)^{3/2}$.  Hence $E[Y_n] = c \sum_i (t_{i+1}-t_i)^{3/2}$.

Now we can bound the latter by
$$E[Y_n] \le c\max(t_{i+1} - t_i)^{1/2} \sum (t_{i+1} - t_i) = cT \max(t_{i+1} - t_i)^{1/2}.$$
I presume that when you say "as $n \to \infty$" you mean "as the mesh size $\max(t_{i+1} - t_i) \to 0$".  Obviously just having more points in our partition won't ensure convergence unless they are actually all getting close to each other.  Thus we indeed have $E[Y_n] \to 0$.

The same idea works for any $p > 2$, using instead that for $Z \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ we have $E[|Z|^p] = c_p \sigma^{p}$, again by scaling, where the value of the constant $c_p$ is irrelevant here.  You will then bound the $p$-variation by $c_p T \max(t_{i+1}-t_i)^{(p-1)/2}$ which likewise goes to zero.

Comment: This might not be directly related to the question but why we use the expectation of quadratic variation (in the definition) instead of simply quadratic variation?

Comment: @TJT: I don't understand what you mean.  The question was about the expectation of $Y_n$ so naturally that is what we are using.